# Some Mp3 Audio Files are not playing

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3

When Playing mp3 Audio Files some songs are playing successfully but some songs are not playing.When decoding audio file  getting error like No Data found when processing input.

```
dec_ctx = fmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->codec;
```

Finding Audio Stream :

```
audio_st = fmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index];
```

Finally I am Decoding Audio

```
if (packet.stream_index == audio_stream_index)
            {
                frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                avcodec_get_frame_defaults(frame);
                got_frame = 0;
                ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(dec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, &packet);
}
```

Here avcodec_decode_audio4 returns the negative value when printing error it shows Inavalid Data Found When Processing input.

I am Using ffmpeg 2.0.1 My configure options are

```
 --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-doc \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --enable-ffplay \
    --enable-ffprobe \
    --enable-ffserver \
    --enable-avdevice \
    --enable-doc \
    --enable-symver \
    --enable-swresample\
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
```

I am not understanding whats the problem?code or any modifications required in ffmpeg configure file.Please Provide any information about this issue.

Comment: Are you getting any log in logcat that look suspicious?

Comment: Thank for Your Response  i am checking  like below if the value is negative then terminate the loop               if (ret < 0)
    {
     LOGE("Error decoding audio\n");
     
        break;
    }